# Why do I get multiple instances of NSDocument but only one window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, instance, nsdocument

In my Document based application, no less than **three** documents are opened when I run the app, yet only one window displays. When I save&quit, it saves *another* document than the one that belongs to the window.

How can this happen? In particular, I do not want multiple instances of `NSDocument`, how can I avoid this at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this has to do with the way that the app was set up in the Interface Builder. The code did not cause this behavior.

So, if seemingly random documents are opening up when starting a doc-based application, remember to **also check you xib settings in IB!**